# Custom bean exception handler not working in camel doCatch in VM route

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have the below code in my camel project. OnExceptionHandler is part of a utility jar, which I am calling in my route to handle the exception. But when I throw the CustomException from the doCatch block of the route it does not go to the onException specified in the OnExceptionHandler, but prints as a VmConsumer error. I would like for the thrown exception to be caught by the onException in the handler class. In other cases such as a direct route it works as expected. But in case of vm and seda route it is not working as expected.

```
public class OnExceptionHandler {

    public static void setup() {
     
        onException(CustomException.class)
        .maxRedeliveries(3)
        .bean(LogErrorBean.class)
        .continued(true)
        .end();
    }
}

public class MyRoute extends Route builder {

    public void configure(){
    
        OnExceptionHandler.setup(this);
        
        from("vm:myroute")
        .doTry()
        .to("jms:jmsqueue")
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
        .throwException(CustomException.class, "Error when sending to queue")
        .end()
        .to("direct:proceed")
        end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question duplicates this one:
[Exception not propagated to error handler in Apache Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194871/exception-not-propagated-to-error-handler-in-apache-camel)

> Camel error handling is disabled
>
> When using doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally then the regular Camel Error
> Handler does not apply. That means any onException or the likes does
> not trigger. The reason is that doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally is in
> fact its own error handler and that it aims to mimic and work like how
> try/catch/finally works in Java.